# Unit test project in CMake with dependency, without transitive dependencies?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, ctest

I'm working on a big project and we're having trouble properly using mocks in our unit tests. The main problem is that we haven't got all dependencies set correctly, but in solving this we find that because of transitive dependencies the unit test projects get a link to the implementation rather than to their mock.

I think this would be solved by making it depend on its unit-under-test without its dependencies, then the mocks, and then any explicit thing you'd want to add to that, but I can't find out how to depend only on the unit-under-test rather than it plus dependencies.

How can I fix this?

As example, the cmakefile is like this:

```
add_library(UnitUnderTest $(SOURCES))
target_link_libraries(UnitUnderTest PUBLIC Sockets SomethingElse)
add_executable(TestForUnit $(TESTSOURCES))
target_link_libraries(TestForUnit PUBLIC UnitUnderTest MockSockets)
```

and TestForUnit first resolves against Sockets (because it's a dependency) and then causes conflicts on MockSockets, as it has the same set of symbols as Sockets does. I really don't want to remove all dependencies everywhere as the unit under test can (and will in many cases) depend on dozens of other components, which you then have to re-specify everywhere, not to mention that you lose access to the include path for that component.

Comment: Example of CMake file would be nice for understand question clearly.

Comment: As I understand, when link `TestForUnit`, you actually want `UnitUnderTest` be linked itself *as is* `target_link_libraries(UnitUnderTest PUBLIC MockSockets SomethingElse)`. If so, you should create *another* target, linked in such way.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, but if you create another target then you're adding the burden, and MockSockets would have to duplicate the interface part of your unit.

Comment: As far as I understand, `MockSockets` should duplicate(implement) interface of `Sockets` in any case. This is purpose of mock objects.

Comment: @tsyvarev it should duplicate the implementation, but not necessarily the interface declaration. Although that does sounds like an option...

Comment: Interface can be declared in, e.g., `socket.h` , be implemented by both `Socket` and `MockSocket` and be used by any library/executable, linked with either `Socket` or `MockSocket`.

Comment: @tsyvarev except that socket.h will live in Socket, whose include path you won't get if you depend on MockSocket. Unless you duplicate the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82498/discussion-between-tsyvarev-and-dascandy).